# iOS Gamecenter - Resubmitting leaderboard scores and earned achievements

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

For iOS game apps using Gamecenter, is it a best practice to re-submit to Gamecenter leaderboard scores and/or earned achievements that the player earned previously, at the time that the player's save game file is loaded?

This could make the player's scores/achievements show up properly in Gamecenter in situations like:

- The player originally earned the leaderboard score or achievement before signing up for Gamecenter;
- The player originally earned the leaderboard score or achievement while they were offline (no Internet connection), and exited the game app while still offline.

Answer (score 0):

You can save player's score in NSUserdefaults Or Database.That data can be retrived in Any time you want.after that you only need to submit data when user press gamecenter button in your Game or when user clear level..etc

Comment: My game doesn't have a GameCenter button, but I do want the user to be able to see their scores/achievements if they go to the GameCenter app.  The game currently tries to report achievements and scores to GameCenter only once: immediately when they are earned. What happens if the user has no Internet connection at that time?